# Create view with if else inside

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to make view or simply to get some data from database but in specific way.

For example if data is :

```
 1 | test | test | 0 | test  
 2 | test | test | 1 | test
 3 | test | test | 1 | test
 4 | test | test | 1 | test
 5 | test | test | 0 | test
```

The output should be:

```
 1 | test | test | FALSE | test  
 2 | test | test | TRUE  | test
 3 | test | test | TRUE  | test
 4 | test | test | TRUE  | test
 5 | test | test | FALSE | test
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [**`CASE`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) expression.

**Query**

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3,
CASE col4 WHEN 0 THEN 'False'
WHEN 1 THEN 'TRUE' 
ELSE NULL END AS col4, col5
FROM your_table_name;
```

Answer (score 3):

An `if` condition in SQL is expressed using [`CASE` expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
SELECT
   id
,  a
,  b
,  CASE c WHEN 0 THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END AS c
,  d
FROM my_table
```

Note that there are two forms of `CASE` expression in SQL Server - simple and searched. The above is an example of a simple.

Answer (score 2):

If 2012+ you can use the inline IF

```
IIF(condition,a,b)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be after a CASE statement. Try this:

```
SELECT 
  Col1, 
  Col2, 
  Col3,
  CASE WHEN Col4 = 0 THEN 'False' WHEN Col4 = 1 Then 'True' ELSE NULL END,
  Col5
FROM YourTableName
```